# Excel Offset: Automating the Reference Cell by using Index Match

Tags: excel, offset, index-match

If the answer was already provided, please feel free to post the link, but I did not see one.

This is a real estate example. I have a table of a lot of properties and information. One of the fields is "Occupancy." I am trying to use the AVERAGE OFFSET functions combined with CELL and INDEX/MATCH to calculate the average Occupancy of the top 5 and top 10 buildings in this table. To accomplish this, I wanted to create a "Summary Table" below the Property table to list the averages.

Specifically:

1. For OFFSET, in the "Reference" section, I want to look up "Occupancy" in my summary cell, use INDEX MATCH to find "Occupancy" in the table, and then;
2. I want the Cell Reference returned AS A VALUE and then move one row down and then highlight the top 5.
3. Most importantly, I want everything cell referenced **without hardcoding** or navigating the table to highlight the cell reference. I am not sure if this is possible, but after pouring through a bunch of articles, I am having trouble finding a solution.

To make things simple, let's pull out all the columns I had in the original table and go off the below. Assume all the data types are in the proper format:

```
     **COLUMN A**       **COLUMN B**
ROW 1 | Properties   | Occupancy   |
ROW 2 | Property A   | 58%         |
ROW 3 | Property B   | 56%         |
ROW 4 | Property C   | 77%         |
ROW 5 | Property D   | 85%         | 
ROW 6 | Property E   | 92%         |

ROW 7

ROW 8 |Top 5         |              |  'NOTE: I used a custom formula to format:                  
                                     "Top "#. Please do not think this is text.

ROW 10|Occupancy     | **CODE HERE**| 'Format is "General"
ROW 11|              |              |
ROW 12|              |              |
```

Here's how I initially coded it in B10:

```
'=AVERAGE(OFFSET(CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$B$1,MATCH(A10,$A$1:$B$1,0))),1,0,5,1))
```

I am getting "there is a problem with your formula" since I am guessing it is due to the cell returning text in lieu of the cell reference as a value. So I error checked myself and stripped out the AVERAGE, OFFSET and put this is B11:

```
'=CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$B$1,MATCH(A10,$A$1:$B$1,0)))
```

I know I get $B$1, so I then put $B$1 to replace the CELL function within B10 to see if my average offset is wrong:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$1,1,0,5,1))
```

I now get the right solution since I went and hardcoded the reference, which does not solve the issue.

If I use INDIRECT and then CELL in B12:

```
'=INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$B$1,MATCH(A10,$A$1:$B$1,0))))
```

I then get the title "Occupancy" and not the cell reference.

Obviously, I am aware of the fact that the CELL function will return text and not a value. I can't use INDIRECT because when I do, INDIRECT will just display the title of the column in text and not return the cell reference as a value. ADDRESS is not useful because you have to hardcode and the goal is to have zero hardcodes.

How can I code finding the cell reference of specific text in a table without actually going to the table to cell reference when I am building out my OFFSET function?

As you can see, I went through a variety of ways to dissect the problem and I would appreciate anyone's help to come to a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your data just in a raw Excel sheet? Are you able to modify the sheet so you can reformat the data into tables, or does it have to stay raw data? (e.g. it's generated from some other utility so not practical to reformat it)

Comment: I kept it as raw data if anyone wanted to try the scenario on their own excel. It's really not that much data. The essence of the question is how to structure the code.

Comment: I understand the essence of your question, my question is are you required to keep it in that structure, or can you reformat it into an Excel table? Tables have some more data processing tools you might be able to use.

Comment: Also, take a look at pivot tables and see if that might be able to get you what you're looking for.

Comment: So are you saying you cannot code an INDEX MATCH within OFFSET for the cell reference? There isn't a way to tailor the OFFSET function? I'm aware of being able to use tables and pivot tables to get to this answer. I'm just asking if what I presented can be done with an OFFSET function to pinpoint a reference.

Comment: Haven't delved far enough into it to know if you can do that or not. I'm just throwing out other possibilities that might make it easier to get what you're after.